# Oracle default Timestamp format

Tags: sql, oracle

I just set default timestamp format as

```
ALTER SESSION SET  NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF'
```

When I insert the data into the table the timestamp inserted as,

```
0014-08-11 04:45:24.000000000
```

When I query

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL
```

I get:

```
11-AUG-14 06.14.58.400000000 PM +04:00
```

But I want the default timestamp as 2014-07-22 05:54:18.000000000.

It would be appreciated if some one could help me on this.

Answer (score 8):

`SYSTIMESTAMP` returns data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`. So you either need to cast it to a plain `TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL;

CAST(SYSTIMESTAMPASTIMESTAMP)
-----------------------------
2014-08-11 15:27:11.091862000
```

Or set the separate `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` parameter:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF';

SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

SYSTIMESTAMP         
----------------------
2014-08-11 15:27:11.35 
1526000
```

Either way you're losing the time zone information, which may or may not matter to you.

But this doesn't have anything to do with querying values from a `TIMESTAMP` (without time zone) column in your table. The value in the table has no format incidentally; the NLS settings when you insert will not affect how it is stored or how it is displayed when queried. You need to specify the format at query time as well as at insert time - and preferably using explicit format models with `TO_TIMESTAMP()` and `TO_CHAR()` rather than replying on NLS settings, which you might not be able to control.

You should also be using `HH24` since you no longer have the AM/PM marker.

Answer (score -1):

There are two solutions to this :

**1. Convert TIMESTAMP/DATE format in Oracle client** (Applicable only for that session)

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6';
```

**2. Define nls_timestamp_format in init.ora**

```
nls_timestamp_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6';
```